# How can I check whether a Revmob Session has started or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, revmob

I have integrated RevMobAds in my app. How can I check whether a RevMob session has started or not?

In the AppDelegate :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:@"My RevMob AppID"];
    return YES;
}

-(void)showAds
{
    banner = [[RevMobAds session] banner]; //banner is an object of RevMobBanner
    banner.delegate = self;
    [banner showAd];
}
```

In my first ViewController :

```
-(void)displayAd
{
    STAppDelegate *appDelegate = (STAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [appDelegate showAds];
}
```

When I call the displayAd function in the viewDidLoad of the first page, some warnings are displayed:-

```
WARNING: SESSION NOT STARTED!! UNEXPECT BEHAVIOUR CAN OCCOUR!!
WARNING: USING ADS WITHOUT STARTING A SESSION COULD PRODUCE UNPREDICTED BEHAVIOUR!
```

Also the ad is not displayed. But when I call the displayAd function after a delay,say 5sec, then everything works well and the ad is displayed, but the problem is that this time interval of 5 secs may vary from time to time.
    So, can anyone suggest me a way to find out whether the RevMob session has started or not so that I can call the displayAd function only after that?

Comment: In case you're still having the issue, you should download the last framework version. They've fixed this recently.

Comment: Thanx @alex-i. They solved this issue in their latest SDK ios 7.4.8

Answer (score 1):

```
[RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:REVMOB_APP_ID
              withSuccessHandler:^{
                  NSLog(@"RevMobAds session started");
              } andFailHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                  NSLog(@"RevMobAds session failed");
              }];
```

Comment: Can you please provide more informations and an explanation what the OP did wrong and how your code fix it? It's just what a quality answer is about.

Comment: @Julian, my code snippet answers the question, "How can I check whether a Revmob Session has started or not?" using the block instead of delegate method. So, I thought that anyone else would find it useful who lands here.

Comment: If I do this way then how would I set delegate. currently I am using [RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:REVMOB_APP_ID andDelegate:self];

Comment: @Alix, you can start the session this way. And utilise session anywhere in the app and can also set delegate as shown in the following snippet. RevMobFullscreen *revMob;
revMob = [[RevMobAds session] fullscreen];
revMob.delegate = self;

Comment: @zeeawan : Yup I did the same. But my delegate methods are not bring called thats why I went to andDelegate approach. but thats also not working. I am confused. :/ any suggestion for me

Comment: Well, startSessionWithAppID should succeed or return an error.